# Can I run nodeunit from cloud9-ide

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide, nodeunit

I would like to know if it is possible to run nodeunit tests within Cloud9 IDE (like I run JUnit tests within IDE like Eclipse).

ps: I use a local Cloud9 IDE, not from c9.io

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, as described in [this blogpost](https://c9.io/site/blog/2011/11/never-commit-to-your-master/) you can write your tests by postfixing your javascript files with `_test` (so, the tests for `project.js` will be in `project_test.js`). And they will run automatically when you save `project.js` (or the test file).

In the near future there will be a test panel available that lists all your unit test files so you can test your whole application with one click.

Comment: Since there are many unit test frameworks, how does cloud9 know which one to use when the file is saved?

Comment: FYI, link is broken as of Jan '14. I realise it's old, however.

Comment: I've tried this tip, and it doesn't seem to do anything. Is this really all you have to do to make it work? This is the first time I've used either node or c9.io, by the way.